# Can´t get value of sum from a selected repeated id (PHP) and (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I´m trying to get a sum from the column of the repeated values that was selected in a form before, but i can´t even show the result, is there something wrong with this code?

DB Structure

table carros
-id
-matricula
-marca

table movimentos
-id
-matricula
-marca
-fornecedor
-tipo
-despesa
-observacoes

i have a form in the file "verificar.dwt.php" that contains a dropdown list with all the values in "matricula" (from the table carros) and when it selects the respective "matricula" it goes to "extra1.dwt.php" where it shows a table with all the repeated rows that have the same "matricula" value.

What i want to show now is the sum of that repeated rows.

```
<a href='verificar.dwt.php'>Voltar atrás</a>

<div align="center"><? 

include 'configmov.dwt.php'; 

$tableName='movimentos';
$matricula = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['matricula']);

$sql="SELECT matricula, marca, despesa FROM ".$tableName." WHERE matricula = '".$matricula."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

$result1 = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM despesa'); 
$row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1); 
$sum = $row1['value_sum'];

$n=1; 

echo "Os seus resultados: <p>";

echo "<table border=0>";
echo "<tr bgcolor='#CCFFCC'>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Matricula</td>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Marca</td>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Despesa</td>";
echo "</tr>";




while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['matricula']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['marca']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['despesa']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo $sum;
}
```

Comment: What's the DB structure?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the database layout as well. It seems you don't filter anything when doing SELECT SUM(value), which would retrieve the SUM of all the values in the table. You probably also want to check the value of mysql_error() after running your queries.

Comment: the user chooses a "matricula" from one table and in the table "movimentos" every repeated value of that "matricula" repeated has a "despesa" and i want to get the sum of the repeated "despesa" of the selected "matricula". Did it sound confusing?

Comment: Are you sure it's not printing `$sum`? It looks good, but you seem to be printing it inside a `<table>` but between rows of the table, so your browser might not display it as you expect. Take a peek in your HTML source and see if it might actually be in there.

Comment: i got it to print $sum but now it just shows the total from the column "despesa" instead of the just the sum of "despesa" of the repeated "matricula"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to show it then you must show it on a column under a row but you closed your row attribute before displaying it may be it creates problem.and one more thing you put this query

```
$result1 = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM despesa');
```

is despesa table name?? as i think it is colname if it is colname then your query should look like this

```
$result1 = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(despesa) AS value_sum FROM Tablename');
```

Comment: 2despesa" is a column from the table "movimentos"

Comment: in that case your query is like that $result1 = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(despesa) AS value_sum FROM movimentos');

Comment: with this what i get is the sum from all the ids from table "movimentos" what i want is to get the value "despesa" of just the repeated "matricula" that are in the table "movimentos"

Comment: with this you will get sum of "despesa". if you want sum of repeated values then use having clause with group by clause.

Comment: SELECT SUM(despesa) AS value_sum FROM movimentos group by matricula having count(matricula)>1

Comment: it´s strange it show the correct value from one "matricula" but when i try another it still show the same result

Comment: may be some modification requires. you can modify it according to your requirement.

Comment: im a newbie with this, what kind of modifications are you implying?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anybody can help you without understanding the content of the tables you use.

But:

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM despesa
```

seems to be at the core of you summing, and it doesn't contain anything from the posting (like matricula).

If I were you I'd start by echo'ing all the SQL and figure out from there what it is you really need to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your first query despesa  is a column

```
$sql="SELECT matricula, marca, despesa FROM ".$tableName." WHERE matricula = '".$matricula."'";
```

so i guess that insted of

```
$result1 = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM despesa');
```

you should use

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(despesa) AS value_sum FROM {$tableName}");
```